# Visual Studio директории включения.

Tags: c, include, c++

Как добавить в Visual Studio дополнительные директории включения файлов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо прописать их полный путь в настройках Visual Studio. Для этого надо пройти Tools->Options..->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories,
далее необходимо выбрать Include files и ввести путь.